# wingpanel lost it's dynamic transparency

Tags: wingpanel, pantheon

okay so i am actually using endeavour os BUT since i use pantheon de i was hoping/praying someone on the elementary forum maybe able to help me. my issue is regarding wingpanel. it is no longer transparent or whatever... it is just 100 percent transparent now but not able to show any dynamic transparency.
i added this to my gtk.css (Dracula theme) per someones suggestion on another site but it didn’t work:

/*********************

```
wingpanel support *
********************/
.panel {
background-color: transparent;
transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}
.panel.maximized {
background-color: #000;
}
```

i also messed around in dconf editor with no luck.
i tried creating a new account but still no luck.
i have no idea what to do. i figured since pantheon de is obviously rooted here in elementary you guys having more expertise than me on this might be able to help. i am hoping so because this to be honest really sucks. thankx in advance for ANY help what so ever.

[image: what it looks like now]

[image: what it used to look like (the correct look)]

Comment: Welcome to the eOS:SE. EndeavourOS is off-topic here but, if wingpanel follows standard CSS, those transitions are triggered by events like `:hover`. It may also be necessary to confirm whether you need `.panel.maximized` or `.panel .maximized`, as spaces will dictate how class styles are applied 

Comment: THANK YOU... for being so kind. it didn't work but regardless thankx friend :-)